# Почему у меня не отображается изображение в CircleImageView?

Tags: android

Всем привет. У меня возникла такая проблема: не отображается аватар в объекте CircleImageView в Android. Библиотека в build.gradle импортировалась без ошибок. С чем это может быть связано? Может картинка маленькая? К сожалению, не могу показать frontend-часть приложения (делаю задание для компании, в которую собираюсь устраиваться), но могу показать кусочек кода в xml:

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/avatar"
            android:layout_width="61.06dp"
            android:layout_height="61.06dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
            android:contentDescription="avatar"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars"
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне, кажется, для начала надо прочитать про компонент:

https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

И найти там такую штуку, где увидеть что `android:src="@drawable/profile"` задаёт изображение:

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:src="@drawable/profile"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
    app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>
```

Comment: Может вместо векторного изображение надо растровое вставлять?